# Service Fabric SDK do not create C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, appfabric

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and the related service fabric SDK.  When trying several samples found on Internet or when creating a simple sample into Visual Studio, I cannot deploy because of this error:

> Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : Unaccessible Image Store URI
>   'C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare' specified.

C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ was created but not the ImageStoreShare.

Creating this ImageStoreShare folder solved my problem.

But is it enough to run my service fabric sample?  Is the SF environment set correctly?  Do I need to specify something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After 1 month using daily the system, it seems that everything is working fine.  Moreover, I had the same issue on another installation and the same scenario fixed the problem.

To summarize, the solution is to create the folder manually:

> C:\SfDevCluster\Data\ImageStoreShare

Comment: Does it answer? Really I don't think so.

Comment: Creating the folder fixed the problem for me. Maybe you should include this workaround in your answer too, now it's only in the question.

Comment: What a simple solution for such an easy problem